# Trying to find if a remote file contains a string in an expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I have an expect script in which I need to know if a remote box has a string.

I have the below command in my expect script to achieve that:

```
set status [catch {exec ssh gn@cm1 "grep -c 'End of Test' /bf/tcl/tcl_scripts/log"} result]
```

But when the *grep* command, cannot find the string it returns an error status (1) to exec, which I am handling using the *catch*. But after this command all expect commands (send, expect etc) stop working.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Could you provide the code with other commands that are not working after the first error?

Comment: What do you mean by *all expect commands (send, expect etc) stop working*? Any error messages?